# Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\arctan{\frac{1}{k}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

You guys have helped me a lot with series and series expansions, thank you all. Let's see if something stuck. I'm going to do this myself and hope on good feedback from you guys.

---

We know that $$\arctan\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{3k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)=\frac{3k^2-1}{3k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^5}\right)=\left(\frac{3k^2-1}{3k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)\right)\frac{1}{k}.$$

Denote $a_k=\arctan(1/2)$ and $b_k=1/k$. We know that $\sum b_k$ is divergent and by the limit comparison test we have

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_k}{b_k}=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{3k^2-1}{3k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)\right)=\frac{3}{3}=1>0,$$

which ultimately implies that $\sum a_k$ has to be divergent too.

Will this do?

Comment: Parseval: yes, it will do.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Pheww.. that first comment scared me at first...thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tail governs thus it diverges, otherwise $\arctan{\frac1k}-\frac1k$ converges.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "the tail"?

Comment: The behavior for k large, it’s a good way to understand whether the series converges or diverges in a fast way. To prove rigorously you can use the tail for the limit test.

Answer (score 1):

$\arctan\frac{1}{k}\sim\frac{1}{k}$, which says that it diverges.

Comment: My professor would never give me full points on a question if I had a motivation like this, evnthough it's correct.

Comment: @Parseval: It's only a sketch, but it's based on a powerful theorem which says series with positive, equivalent near $\infty$, terms both converge or both diverge. There remains only to cite the theorem (+1).

Answer (score 0):

$\arctan(x)$ is concave on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence for any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\arctan x\geq \frac{\pi x}{4}$ and the given series is trivially divergent by comparison with the harmonic series.